# Wikimedia API image search with public domain filter

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, wikimedia-commons

I would like to query Wikimedia API to find all images that contain a keyword and filter only the images that are public domain. So no additional CC-SA license.

Curently I'm using the following query to extract the images:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=roses&srnamespace=6&srinfo=totalhits%7Csuggestion&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Cscore%7Csnippet%7Ctitlesnippet%7Credirecttitle%7Credirectsnippet%7Csectiontitle%7Csectionsnippet%7Chasrelated&srredirects=&srlimit=10&generator=images&titles=Wikipedia%3APublic_domain&gimlimit=10

But this is curently returning all the images regardless of their licencing. Maybe I need to modify the namespace but I don't know where to look.

Thanks

Comment: If you found public domain images useful, consider contributing back to the commons, e.g. by improving the machine-readable metadata available for everyone. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/File_metadata_cleanup_drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, your current api query does two very distinct things:

- get the first 10 images from the page [Wikipedia:Public Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPublic_domain) - the `pages` result, you could specify additional properties to get for that result set
- search the namespace 6 for the word *roses*

Unfortunately, you can't restrict the [search module](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aSearch) to search only in some categories, you can only limit it to a single namespace. So you would need to get the categories of all search results and filter them yourself for images in the [Category:Public Domain](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPublic_domain) (and all its [subcategories](http://toolserver.org/~magnus/catscan_rewrite.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&depth=5&categories=Public+domain&comb%5Blist%5D=1&doit=1)). The API query would look like

> `api.php?action=query&prop=`[`imageinfo`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#imageinfo_.2F_ii)`|`[`categories`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#categories_.2F_cl)`&`[`generator`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Generators)`=search&gsrsearch=roses&gsrnamespace=6&format=json`

Don't forget to [continue the query](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries), if you want 10 images that match your category criteria you might need to query (a lot) more than that.

Comment: I think adding `clcategories` might make sense here to limit the categories only to Category:Public Domain and its subcategories. Doing this would most likely mean less `query-continue`.

Comment: Nah, `clcategories` does unfortunately not work because it doesn't incorporate subcategories - and you can't pass all 1200 subcats in there

Comment: *Unfortunately, you can't restrict the search module to search only in some categories* - sure you can, just add `incategory:<category name>` to the search query.

Comment: OK, you could do that (although it's not really a [URL] parameter), but this still doesn't include subcategories. You'd have to do something like *`search_string` +* `incategory:"Public Domain" OR incategory:CC-zero OR …`, and that likely goes above the search string length limit.

Comment: if I append +incategory:"Public Domain" or anything to the `srsearch` parameter, it returns the following error:
`{
servedby: "srv292",
error: {
code: "srsearch-text-disabled",
info: "text search is disabled"
}
}`

Comment: Hm, [worksforme](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo|categories&generator=search&gsrsearch=roses%20incategory:%22Public%20Domain%22&gsrnamespace=6&gsrwhat=text&format=jsonfm&servedby). The error message is unambiguous, but I don't think the Wikipedia servers are inproperly configured.